# Notification Schema Structure in MongoDB-NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, notifications, schema

I am developing notification process & technology I am using is MongoDB & NodeJS(Express)
Please do let me know how to design schema for this notification process.
What are the collections & documents will be defined.

Thanks

Comment: I acknowledge that you are new to Stack Overflow, however, when posting a question, [it is expected that *a lot* of research and effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) is put into solving the problem by yourself before posting a question here. As it currently stands, I do not believe you have done enough research or put enough effort into solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot, I wrote my schema in a flowing way. It has helped me to keep scalability in my application and do the best solution for multiple notification features.

```js
NotificationSchema   = new Schema({
    sender: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}, // Notification creator
    receiver: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}], // Ids of the receivers of the notification
    message: String, // any description of the notification message 
    read_by:[{
     readerId:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
     read_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    }],
    created_at:{type: Date, default: Date.now},
    
});
```

**Why this looks best notification schema to me:**

Let’s explain the schema, I wrote here and what things can be done with this solution.

**Sender**: I have to keep the sender field as an object, the object is referred to as a user collection for the population. Because the notification happens generally for a single action, I mean it may create from the activity of a single person. So, the sender is who is sending this notification, the source of the notification.

**Receiver**: I have kept the receiver field as an array of objects and the object is referred to user collection if needed for the population. The receiver can be one person or many persons. So, the receiver field will hold the IDs of the recipients.

**Message**: message field is used for holding the notification message details.

**Read_by**: the read_by field is an array of two object properties. this object contain readerId(user-id) and read_at (the seen date-time). The read_by array reduced many works and has given more advanced options to work with. It will be used to track each recipient’s view time to track. So, the notification sender can track which recipient has read the message at which time.

**Created_at**: this field simply holds the notification creation date and time.

So, this schema is very helpful to use for making notifications from one to one and one to many. That’s why I have considered it as the best notification schema for the MongoDB database.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar for the quick & explained reply, let me check if it works for me

Comment: If it's working, please upvote the answer, it'll help me write more of such.

Comment: This way, isn't it hard to query notifications which belong to a particular user?